# How to change the temporary variable value outside the timer?

Tags: c#

As question, i need to keeps check for wheather the folder is created in 3 minutes... initially, i set myVar to 0  and everytime the timer run, it will keep add until 3 in the else part and perform the other function. Anybody can assist me in this matter as I'm not familiar in parshing data out the timers...

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int myVar = 0;
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 60000; // Currently set to 1 minutes
        timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => timer_Elapsed(sender, e, myVar);
        timer.Start();
    }

    static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e, int myVar)
    {
        DirectoryInfo imagepath = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users");

        DirectoryInfo[] directoryInfo = imagepath.GetDirectories();

        string directoryFolderName = "";
        string subdirectoryFolderName = "";
        string fullPathName = "";


        foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in directoryInfo)
        {
            directoryFolderName = directory.Name;
        }

        if (directoryFolderName.Contains("ABB"))
        {

            fullPathName = imagepath + "\\" + directoryFolderName;
            DirectoryInfo path = new DirectoryInfo(fullPathName);
            DirectoryInfo[] subdirectoryInfo = path.GetDirectories(); ;

            foreach (DirectoryInfo subDirectory in subdirectoryInfo)
              subdirectoryFolderName = subDirectory.Name;


            if (subdirectoryFolderName.Contains("folder"))
            {
                string tempPath = fullPathName + "\\" + "folder";
                mainFunction(path, imagepath);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fullPathName);
                Console.WriteLine("tif folder not found!!!");
                string msg = "Program failed unexpectedly. Error Msg: folder not found!!!";
                WriteExceptionFile(msg, null);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Minutes: " + myVar);
            myVar += 1;
        }
}
```

Comment: Bit complicated, some reason you aren't using the FileSystemWatcher class

Comment: Try `static void timer_Elapsed(... e, ref int myVar)`.

Comment: You did not show what you want to do after 3 mins, but in that case why not use `Task` with delay, that would work better and probably be a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `int` is passed by value, which means when you update the variable inside your `timer_elapsed` method it is not reflected outside that method.

A simple solution is to force the int to be passed by reference using the `ref` keyword:

```
static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e, ref int myVar){ ... }
```

Here's a simple demo: https://rextester.com/UOBCK74072

Comment: This solution is not thread safe. The variable `myVar` is updated from one thread and is accessed from another thread, without locking.

Answer (score 0):

You send myVar as a parameter. So, changes in method cannot changes main variables value.
You can define myVar static and change it's value directly.Or you can use global variable out of main method.

```
    static int x = 0;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x); // before call foo->0
        foo();
        Console.WriteLine(x); // after call foo -> 10
        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    public static void foo()
    {
        x = 10;
    }
```

Comment: Ya, i try definr it outside just now. but i only can call it if i delete the static from the timer_Elapsed but it cause some error message for timer_Elapsed in my main. Can assist me to write it? Im no idea T.T

Comment: You can use like my edits. And also call by referance like ref myValue

Answer (score -1):

Use out keyword to get the updated value from your timer callback

`static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e, out int myVar)
{ ... }`

This should work.